# How to assign names to List of Objects in a property

Tags: c#, properties, uiuserinterfacestyle

[image]I use the following code to create a list of objects that can be assigned with values and have unique names in the UI.

```
public class Test
{
        
  
private int _length;
private Color _color;
private Dictionary<string,object> array2 = new ();
 

           
  [Display(Name = "List of Objects")]
  public Dictionary<string, object> ObjectList
  {
        get { return array2; }
        set { array2 = value; }
  }
    
  public Test()
  {
        array2.Add("test1",_length);
        array2.Add("test2", _color);
 }
   
....
}
```

For result pls. see attached file !

[image]

How can I remove/change string "Count:" - string in second column (upper  right corner) ?

When I use GroupName in DisplayAttribute this will have no effect, how can I change UI-look by also grouping values ?

e.g. [Display(Name = "List of Objects", GroupName = "XYZ")]

I can also not select colors anymore, which worked when I used List.

Comment: Is the goal to create a list of user modifiable properties? Using what UI framework? Should the user be able to add/remove items as well?

Comment: If you want to name things, then you can use a List of `KeyValuePairs` or a `Dictionary`, but with a `Dictionary` you can only have unique names as a key.

Comment: Sound like you want dictionary instead of list.

Comment: Is the goal to create a list of user modifiable properties? => YES                       Using what UI framework? => I dont know, I work on a plugin dll for a 3rd party application, how can i find that out ? Should the user be able to add/remove items as well? => NO.

Comment: If you want to name each of the values, can you list what those names be? Is there a criteria? do you get those names from that list itself or somewhere else?

Comment: I assign the names in the code, the names will not change.

Comment: Dictionary works, see picture above. The remaining problem is the Count:-string and it seems that iam not any longer able to select colors. The names are just strings like in the example above. array2.Add("test1",_length);
array2.Add("test2", _color);

Comment: If dictionary works, I think you should update the question with what needs to happen next. Can you also update the code with which you created the dictionary?

Comment: Yeah, you should just create a class with the properties that you want and set the values there. Or if you don't want to create a separate class, you can also return `dynamic`. https://dotnetfiddle.net/0kn8j0